# Visual studio code - how to copy search results?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does Visual Studio Code have any way to copy the results of a search into a new window?

As a bonus, I'd really like to be able to drop the file name and just copy the lines containing the text of my search results to a new window.

For example, I'd like to to be able to copy the results of the search below to a new editor window. I don't mind if I need to install an extension to do it.

[image]

Comment: can you just shift-click and select everything? Then right-click and copy?

Comment: couldn't get that to work. Tried all the options on the `Selection` menu as well (`Select All`, `Expand` etc.) with no luck

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that - you should file a feature request on github for it.

Comment: Upvote features here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8594 (copy path) and here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17920 (copy search results)

Comment: 1 point for Sublime Text.  There's many benefits to simply putting the search results in an "editor".

Comment: on linux I use `ALT+F3`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

VSCode 1.23 added the ability to copy your search results, see [release notes: copy search results](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_copy-results-from-search-context-menu).

> The search results tree context menu includes three new options: Copy,
> Copy Path, and Copy All. This was a highly 'd request which will
> make it easier to share or export your search results.

The results are not very pretty or clickable when copied/pasted, so be forewarned.  There is an issue tracking the "copy search results" format (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68877) and it is on the 2019 Roadmap (see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Roadmap#workbench) so hopefully it will be improved.

---

**Update as of v1.41** you can move your search results to a new editor and easily select all and copy there.  After searching (which can work across multiple files); click the "Open in Editor" link, as shown in this demo:

[image: search results copy in a new editor]

Another advantage of the search editor is that you can get "**context**" around your search result.  So you can get some number of lines before and after the whole line with your search term in it.  And, of course, line numbers will be copied too.

[image: search editor context demo]

---

And you can just **save** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> the search results editor itself!  And cut lines from there.  Or add notes.  With syntax highlighting.  It will ask where you want to save it, defaulting to the folder where you initiated the search.  It will be named like `yourFolder\yourSearchTerm.code-search`.

---

For more info on the new search editor, see https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_search-editors and

Comment: Note that the "move your search to an editor" feature is experimental, so you have to enable the "Search: Enable Search Editor Preview" option to use it (currently using 1.42).

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66353798/836330 for more on copying search results if you just want your search matches copied.

Answer (score 280):

The following works for a single file:

1. CTRL + F
2. Type your search string
3. CTRL + SHIFT + L to select all occurrences found (max. 999)
4. ESC (or close search dialog with top-right X)
5. CTRL + I to select whole lines
6. CTRL + C
7. Open new file
8. CTRL + V

Comment: Awesome tip. Thank you very much, really handy i nsome situations to extract relevant rows!

Comment: CTRL + i dont work for me , i just search with regexp  ^.+(mysearch).+$ to just select al line with CTRL+SHIFT+L

Comment: Just a little note, I had over 5K results and was able to copy/paste them all. There was no 999 maximum. Could have been updated since the answer was given

Comment: Cmd + Shift + L on Mac

Comment: Great tip, if you don't want the full line, then control shift + arrow keys are useful for selecting word boundaries. This is really useful if you have regex which is matching varying lengths.

Comment: 1-3 + 6 was enough for me.

Comment: how did you find this? I don't know what these commands do
CTRL + SHIFT + L to select all occurrences found (max. 999)
CTRL + I to select whole lines

Comment: For step 5, I need to use `Shift + Alt + I` (version: 1.67.2).

Comment: For step 3 I needed to use Alt+Enter

Comment: Has more steps but works like a charm . thank you sir.

Comment: You have to use `CMD + L` for macOS to select whole lines

Answer (score 37):

Select all occurrences of current selection

CTRL+SHIFT+L

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Comment: `Command + Shift + L` on macOS

Answer (score 17):

As of 12/2020 `CTRL + SHIFT + L` doesn't work (for me)

After search results are rendered, right-click onto the text file and select "Change all occurrences"(or CTRL+F2). This will automatically select the the matched text items. Then you can simply copy it.

Comment: this is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This will work for a single file, assuming each line you care about begins with the search text:
 1. Highlight your search string
 2. CTRL + SHIFT + L to select all occurrences found
 3. SHIFT + ↓ to select all of those lines
 4. CTRL + C
 5. Open a new file
 6. CTRL + V

Answer (score 5):

There's now an "Open in editor" button under search inputs
[image]

Comment: Isn't that point already in the accepted answer?

Comment: @Mark yes. The accepted answer could include a clearer screenshot, like Renaud provided here. The accepted answer didn't  use the language "Open in Editor" ( but I edited to include that; and reference the GIF demo in accepted answer which DOES show the clear "Open in Editor" link)

Answer (score 3):

Wrong. Per the document the correct format is to use Right Alt + Enter, the use Ctrl + C and then open a new tab and paste your results with Ctrl + V

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcuts didn't work for me on my Mac and with the latest VSCode release.

I could copy all search results with the
[right-click menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Z8r.png)