# VS Code find result panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to print search results (Ctrl+Shift+F) to horizontal panel?

Current vertical view is really inconvenient for me as I see only small part of line. Thanks

[image: vscode search results]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: see [Visual studio code - how to copy search results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961368/visual-studio-code-how-to-copy-search-results/50164601#50164601) The new search editor makes seeing and copying the results much more user-friendly.

And now you can just drag the Search view into the Panel.

---

v1.21 has helped this problem.  See [Horizontal panel search](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_horizontal-search)

> // Preview: controls if the search will be shown as a view in the
> sidebar or as a panel in the panel area for more horizontal space.
> Next release search in panel will have improved horizontal layout and
> this will no longer be a preview.

```
 "search.location": "panel",
```

I don't think you can print those results yet but at least the view is much improved.  I don't think you meant actually "print" but nevertheless...

EDIT: Functionality added after the original answer:::

You can now `right-click` anywhere in the search results and select "`Copy All`" to get all the search results into the clipboard.  That context menu has some other options as well.

Answer (score 5):

As of May 2020, the accepted answer is marked by VSCode as a deprecated setting, and no longer works.

Instead, use the Command Palette to find for "Open New Search Editor" to get a full-screen search experience. This option is not bound to a keyboard shortcut by default, and you'll have to do that separately (would be nice to have it as the default, IMO).

Comment: The link in the first line of my answer is all about the Search Editor.  Mods get mad when I cross-post the same info... so I link to the more complete answer elsewhere.