# vscode: add the seach feature to the left bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

My search feature icon in vscode was on the left bar, as default, under the file explorer and above the git icon. The icon was a magnifying glass.

Accidentally, I clicked on some option while right-clicking on it, and now it moved to the bottom bar (the one with the terminal for instance), so now my left and bottom bars appear as the following:

[image] 
[image]

**I want this undone, so the search feature stays in my left bar with a magnifying glass icon**.

Thanks in advance, I googled about this and I'm surprised I didn't found any solution fast.

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793334/vs-code-find-result-panel/49211483#49211483

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the search results?

or

```json
"search.location": "sidebar",
```

or

Under File->Preferences->Settings look for Features->Search. You can select the desired location of the search panel there.

Comment: Thanks! I tried right clicking in the top of the bar and it didn't show the option to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Under File->Preferences->Settings look for Features->Search. You can select the desired location of the search panel there.

Comment: this answer is more clear, thanks