# Is it possible to save the search results of Find in Files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This seems like it should be easy.  I just want to be able to save or copy and paste the results of a Find in Files search in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961368/visual-studio-code-how-to-copy-search-results/50164601#50164601 The ability to copy your search results was added in v.1.23