# How to get the list of files in search results in VS code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to search a string in the code base. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> should do it, but I want to get the list of files in search results.

I tried using the VS Code command:

```js
commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.findInFiles");
```

However, it simply did the search but didn't return anything.

Is there an API to get the list of search results?

Comment: You're asking for a feature that it wouldn't really make sense for VSCode to have. From a programmer's perspective, you need to find by keyword and symbol most often. If you don't, then like @theMayer said, try to use a terminal command like `find`.

Answer (score 3):

The [Copy All right-click command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961368/visual-studio-code-how-to-copy-search-results) in the Search Results pane will get you the entire search results, including the file names.

You can then use regex find/replace to delete the results, leaving only the file names.

Comment: Actually you might not need to explicitly use regex.  Assuming you want the path and name of each file, once you copy all, you paste the search results into a new document.  Then in the new doc, you select all lines that contain the path/file name.  If all paths contain the same sub-string, e.g. `C:\myfolder\myproject`, then you can select that text and hit ctrl+shift+L to select all instances of that string (with VSCode's multi cursor feature), then you select the entire line.  Then you copy, and paste into a new document.  Sounds a little convoluted, but it was really just a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I am getting the files from a search across files result.  This is after the `workbench.action.findInFiles` command has been run.

```js
/**
 * Get the relative paths of the current search results 
 * for the next `runInSearchPanel` call  
 * 
 * @returns array of paths or undefined  
 */
exports.getSearchResultsFiles = async function () {

    await vscode.commands.executeCommand('search.action.copyAll');
    let results = await vscode.env.clipboard.readText();

    if (results)  {
        // regex to get just the file names
        results = results.replaceAll(/^\s*\d.*$\s?|^$\s/gm, "");
        let resultsArray = results.split(/[\r\n]{1,2}/);  // does this cover all OS's?

        let pathArray = resultsArray.filter(result => result !== "");
        pathArray = pathArray.map(path => this.getRelativeFilePath(path))

        return pathArray.join(", ");
    }
    else {
        // notifyMessage?
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

It is designed to get the relative paths of those files, you can change that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

On your search tab, press the little triangle thing next to the search box. It will expand to offer a find/replace in files capability (assuming you’re on the latest version).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, but what I want is a list of strings of file names. Is there an API that I can get the list?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Select one file using `ctrl+click`
2. `ctrl+A` to select all files
3. mouse `right click`
4. `Copy All`

[image]